# How Do I Add A Virtual Attribute To The Attributes Hash in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attr-accessible

I want to add a virtual attribute to an activerecord object.  It's straightforward to define the getter/setter but I want my attribute to appear in the attributes hash (and attribute_names etc..).  Since this is rails 4 I can't use attr_accessible.

What more do I need to add to this code so I can call reference.attributes and have the value of authors show up there?

```
class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base

  def authors
    self.author_names.to_a.join(' and ')
  end

  def authors=(val)
    self.author_names.destroy
    val.strip.split(/(?:[ ]and[ ])|\;/).each {|entry|
     self.author_names << AuthorName.new(name: entry)
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Under what context do you want "the attribute to appear"? `attr_accessor` attributes can be used with `form_for` and mass-assigned in `.update()`.

Comment: Both mass assigned and in the response to .attributes

Comment: Just set `attr_accessor :authors`

Answer (score 5):

```
def attributes
  super.merge({'authors' => authors})
end
```